# androids studio sqlite issue with selectionArgs argument

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have the following function in android studio, which is supposed to return a sqlite cursor.
The problem comes in the selectionArgs argument. Whenever I am passing more than one value to it, it returns a cursor with 0 records.

```
    public Cursor getCursor(String strListWhere, String strTable, String strCols) {

        String strColsToReturn = mySqliteHandler.getWhereColNamesFromJsonString(strListWhere);
        String strArgs = mySqliteHandler.getWhereColArgsFromJsonString(strListWhere);

        Log.d(TAG, "qqqq9: " + strArgs);

        String strTableName = strTable;
        String[] strColumnsToReturn = { strCols };
        String strSelectWhere = strColsToReturn ;
        String[] strSelectArgs = { strArgs };
        Cursor csrResult = sqLiteDatabase.query(true, strTableName, strColumnsToReturn, strSelectWhere, strSelectArgs, null, null, null, null);

        Log.d(TAG, "qqqq9: " + csrResult.getCount());

        return  csrResult;

    }
```

The value in strColsToReturn is `animal_class = ? and province_name = ?`
The value in strArgs is `Bird, KwaZulu-Natal`
So I want it to be `animal_class = 'Bird' and province_name = 'KwaZulu-natal'`

When I only pass one value it works, for example 
The value in strColsToReturn is `animal_class = ?`
The value in strArgs is `Bird`

Can anyone assist?

EDIT: the following code works:

```
    public Cursor getCursor(String strListWhere, String strTable, String strCols) {

        String strColsToReturn = mySqliteHandler.getWhereColNamesFromJsonString(strListWhere);
        List<String> arrWhere = new ArrayList<String>();
        arrWhere = mySqliteHandler.getWhereArray(strListWhere);

        String[] finalValue = new String[ arrWhere.size() ];
        arrWhere.toArray( finalValue );

        String strTableName = strTable;
        String[] strColumnsToReturn = { strCols };
        String strSelectWhere = strColsToReturn ;
        Cursor csrResult = sqLiteDatabase.query(true, strTableName, strColumnsToReturn, strSelectWhere, finalValue, null, null, null, null);

        return  csrResult;

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value for `strColumnsToReturn` should be an array with the names of the columns that you want returned, like:

```
new String[] {column1, column2, column3}
```

where `column1, column2, column3` are strings.
The value for `strSelectWhere` should be the string:

```
"animal_class = ? and province_name = ?"
```

and the value of `strSelectArgs` should be a string array with the parameters that you pass to each of the `?` placeholders of `strSelectWhere`:

```
new String {"Bird", "KwaZulu-Natal"}
```

You can find more [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query(boolean,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

Comment: Thank you, I've edited the original post with a function that now works.